# Dynamically add class to label tag of particular field in django admin

Tags: python, django

I have this model. I'm trying to make the label tag for the 'info' field change background-color, if approved=True.
Here my models and admin files

models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    info = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

admin.py

```
class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel


class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelAdminForm
    list_display = ('name', 'info', 'approved',)

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('name', 'info')
        }),

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelAdminForm
    list_display = ('name', 'info_colored', 'approved',)
    readonly_fields = ('info_colored',)

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('name', 'info', 'info_colored',)
        }),

    )

    def info_colored(self, obj):
        color = 'red'
        if obj.approved:
            color = 'green'
        return u'<b style="background:{};">{}</b>'.format(color, obj.info)
    info_colored.allow_tags = True
    info_colored.admin_order_field = 'info'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This did a bit different then I wanted, but I like this solution even better :)
Cheers!

Comment: When I try the code above, it displays the raw html like here:  <b style=background:green;>New</b>. What am i missing?